# When was the hydrogen's absolute mass found first in history?

Tags: chemistry, atomic-theory

When was hydrogen's absolute mass i.e, in Kg, was found for the first time.
What method was used and what information from earlier researches were used for it?

Also was there any method at that time to calculate number of atoms in a gram sample?

Comment: Your questions are interesting but you will get a better response, if you include your findings. Have you searched Google Scholar, or even Google Books? I usually start from from early 1900 chemistry/physics books which mostly freely available.